# Что за тип данных PUCHAR

Tags: c++, winapi

Вчера увидел какой-то чужой код в котором использовался тип данных PUCHAR
Было что то вроде `(PUCHAR)text` мне очень хотелось бы знать что за PUCHAR и в каких случаях он используется

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PUCHAR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#puchar) - это указатель на [UCHAR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#uchar), определен как

```
typedef UCHAR *PUCHAR;
```

[UCHAR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#uchar) - это беззнаковый CHAR, определен как

```
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
```